# GET request to display in html(Ruby on Rails)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, api

I'm trying to display the response of my GET request on my HTML page in Ruby on Rails.
the following code sends me back the url of the response and when I test that url in Postman, I get the good profile ID. I want to display this ID on my HTML page but I don't know how to access the JSON file to do so and display the ID only.

I'm trying to do something like this on my html, which is wrong.

```
<h3> identified Profile</h3>
<p id="profile"></p>
<pre><%= @response.to_json %></pre>
```

My GET request inside the controller looks like this:

```
def selectedProfile
    require 'net/http'
    require "uri"

    url = params[:url]

    uri = URI.parse(url)

    http = Net::HTTP.new(uri.host, uri.port)
    request = Net::HTTP::Get.new(uri.request_uri)
    # Request headers
    request['Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key'] = 'KEY GOES HERE'

    http.use_ssl = true

    response = http.request(request)

    render json: {identifiedProfile: response.body}
end
```

Response in Postman

```
{
"status": "succeeded",
"createdDateTime": "2022-01-07T16:22:04.417735Z",
"lastActionDateTime": "2022-01-07T16:22:14.5041456Z",
"processingResult": {
    "confidence": "Low",
    "identifiedProfileId": "What I want to display"
}
```

}

Comment: Don't do the HTTP call inline in your controller. Its going to be very hard to test it. Instead create a separate class (a client) that your controller calls and which is allowed to touch the application boundry. That way you can test the HTTP call bit in isolation.

Answer (score 0):

I think there was a problem with my formatting so basically this is what fixed it.

added the GET request formatting in the controller like so:

```
respond_to do |format|
        format.json  { render :json => response.body }      
    end
```

and selected the ID of my ajax call in my script like so:

```
  function getRequest(data) {
$.ajax({
        url: "/identification/selectedProfile",
        type: "GET",
        beforeSend: function(xhr) {xhr.setRequestHeader('X-CSRF-Token', $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content'))},
        data: {url: data},
        success: function(data) {
            $('#profile').text(data['processingResult']['identifiedProfileId'])
        }
    });
```

and everything worked